# Can %NOTFOUND return null after a fetch?

Tags: oracle, plsql, database-cursor

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11271739/458741) raised a very interesting point; there seems to be a contradiction in the Oracle documentation on whether it's possible for `%NOTFOUND` to be null after a fetch. Is it?

To quote from the [11g documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/static.htm#LNPLS546)

> Note: In Example 6-16, if FETCH never fetches a row, then c1%NOTFOUND
>   is always NULL and the loop is never exited. To prevent infinite
>   looping, use this EXIT statement instead: EXIT WHEN c1%NOTFOUND OR
>   (c1%NOTFOUND IS NULL);

The documentation seems to directly contradict itself as it also says the following, which implies that after a fetch `%NOTFOUND` *cannot* be null.

> %NOTFOUND (the logical opposite of %FOUND) returns:
>   NULL after the explicit cursor is opened but before the first fetch
>   FALSE if the most recent fetch from the explicit cursor returned a row
>   TRUE otherwise

The [10g documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/cursor_attributes.htm#LNPLS01311) has a similar warning, which isn't, necessarily, a direct contradiction as it warns that a fetch might not execute successfully in order for this behaviour to be exhibited.

> Before the first fetch, %NOTFOUND evaluates to NULL. If FETCH never
>   executes successfully, the EXIT WHEN condition is never TRUE and the
>   loop is never exited. To be safe, you might want to use the following
>   EXIT statement instead:
>
> EXIT WHEN c1%NOTFOUND OR c1%NOTFOUND IS NULL;

In what situations might a fetch either "fail" or might `%NOTFOUND` return null after a fetch has been executed?

Answer (score 8):

I can find a situation where a fetch can fail:

```
declare
  i integer;
  cursor c is
    select 1 / 0 from dual;
begin
  open c;

  begin
    fetch c
      into i;
  exception
    when others then
      dbms_output.put_line('ex');
  end;

  if c%notfound is null then
    dbms_output.put_line('null');
  elsif c%notfound then
    dbms_output.put_line('true');
  else
    dbms_output.put_line('false');
  end if;
  close c;

end;
```

But this only makes your question stronger since it will evaluate to null, neither in 10g nor in 11g ...

Comment: +1 for being overly smart about it :-). The examples in the documentation didn't have nested anonymous blocks...

Answer (score 0):

I think the part that's tripping you up is this:

> If FETCH never executes successfully, the EXIT WHEN condition is never TRUE and the loop is never exited.

Somewhere in the past there must have been a code example which looked like this:

```
LOOP
  FETCH c1 INTO name;
  EXIT WHEN c1%NOTFOUND;
  -- Do stuff
END LOOP;
```

Given this chunk of code, then the statement rings true. If the fetch never executes (fails), then %NOTFOUND will be null. The `EXIT WHEN` condition will not evaluate to TRUE (null evaluates to false). Then, indeed, the loop will continue forever.

Comment: Why would the fetch never execute in that situation though?

Comment: There could be a problem with the query where it is valid syntactically but fails due to other factors.

Comment: The point of the question is _what_ are those other factors :-)? I can't think of a single way in which the code will get past the fetch in order to evaluate the `%notfound` yet the fetch will not have "worked".

Comment: I'm as guilty as the documentation when it comes to bad examples and wording. The fetch, even if there's an error, should result in the %notfound to be true or false. It is only null before the first fetch (as described earlier in the docs). So, if the `FETCH` never executes (successfully or otherwise) then the %notfound is null.

Answer (score -1):

This is a situation that is easily tested:

```
SET SERVEROUT ON;

DECLARE
  -- this cursor returns a single row
  CURSOR c1 IS
    SELECT 1 FROM dual WHERE rownum = 1;

  -- this cursor returns no rows
  CURSOR c2 IS
    SELECT 1 FROM dual WHERE 1=0;

  v1 number;
BEGIN
  OPEN c1;
  FETCH c1 INTO v1; -- this returns a record
  FETCH c1 INTO v1; -- this does not return a record
  IF c1%NOTFOUND THEN
    dbms_output.put_line('c1%NOTFOUND: TRUE');
  ELSIF c1%NOTFOUND IS NULL THEN
    dbms_output.put_line('c1%NOTFOUND: NULL');
  ELSE
    dbms_output.put_line('c1%NOTFOUND: FALSE');
  END IF;
  CLOSE c1;

  OPEN c2;
  FETCH c2 INTO v1; -- this does not return a record
  IF c2%NOTFOUND THEN
    dbms_output.put_line('c2%NOTFOUND: TRUE');
  ELSIF c2%NOTFOUND IS NULL THEN
    dbms_output.put_line('c2%NOTFOUND: NULL');
  ELSE
    dbms_output.put_line('c2%NOTFOUND: FALSE');
  END IF;
  CLOSE c2;
END;
/
```

The output of the script on Oracle APEX 4.1 is (I think APEX is running Oracle 11gR2, but you can easily run the script on any version):

```
c1%NOTFOUND: TRUE
c2%NOTFOUND: TRUE
```

Based on this test, `%NOTFOUND` will not be NULL after a fetch has been executed.  This matches what the 10g and 11g documentation says in the initial description of the `%NOTFOUND` attribute.  The note about the loop never exiting must be from an old version of the example.  Since it's just a note, I'd says it's safe to trust the initial description and disregard the note.