# Cursor error in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle10g

I'm trying to implement a cursor, & after solving many errors I've finally come to a point where it runs, but it goes into infinite loop...
I've put the image of table below as image.
Aim of cursor: to calculate bowling average & store in 'bowling_avg' column.
here's the cursor code :

```
DECLARE
CURSOR  BOWL_AVG IS SELECT SID,MATCHES,BOWLING_AVG,WICKETS
FROM BOWLING_STATS ;
NSID BOWLING_STATS.SID%TYPE;
NMATCHES BOWLING_STATS.MATCHES%TYPE;
NBOWLING_AVG BOWLING_STATS.BOWLING_AVG%TYPE;
NWICKETS BOWLING_STATS.WICKETS%TYPE;

BEGIN
OPEN BOWL_AVG;
IF BOWL_AVG%ISOPEN THEN
LOOP
    FETCH BOWL_AVG INTO NSID,NMATCHES,NBOWLING_AVG,NWICKETS;
EXIT WHEN BOWL_AVG%NOTFOUND;
IF BOWL_AVG%FOUND THEN
LOOP
UPDATE BOWLING_STATS SET BOWLING_AVG=NWICKETS/NMATCHES WHERE SID=NSID ;
EXIT WHEN BOWL_AVG%NOTFOUND;
END LOOP;
END IF;
END LOOP;
ELSE
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('UNABLE TO OPEN CURSOR');
END IF; 
CLOSE BOWL_AVG;
END;
```

[image]

I'm running this in oracle database 10g.
I ask for assistance in finding the error.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why all your code in capital letters?

Comment: my professor believes capital letters make it easier to find errors...

Comment: :-), that's both the best and worst answer I've heard to that question! You have far too many loops here, that's why. Remove all bar the outer one.

Comment: There are many coding styles for many programming languages and not even one of them says that all your code should be in capital letter.

Comment: @Ben,yes,I agree with that...

Comment: Ask your professor why road signs are not in capital letters on motorways/freeways/autobahns/your local equivalent.

Comment: yeah, I'm waiting till he puts grades on my project !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding whitespace to your code makes it clearer what you're doing:

```
declare

   cursor bowl_avg is
   select sid, matches, bowling_avg, wickets
     from bowling_stats;

   nsid bowling_stats.sid%type;
   nmatches bowling_stats.matches%type;
   nbowling_avg bowling_stats.bowling_avg%type;
   nwickets bowling_stats.wickets%type;

begin

   -- 1. Open Cursor              
   open bowl_avg;

   -- 2. Check if Cursor is open
   if bowl_avg%isopen then
      -- 3. Loop
      loop
         -- 4. Get record
         fetch bowl_avg into nsid, nmatches, nbowling_avg, nwickets;
         -- 5. Exit if no records left
         exit when bowl_avg%notfound;

         -- 6. If there is a record
         if bowl_avg%found then
            -- 7. Loop
            loop
               update bowling_stats 
                  set bowling_avg = nwickets / nmatches 
                where sid = nsid;
               -- 8. Exit if there is no record.
               exit when bowl_avg%notfound;
            end loop;
         end if;

      end loop;
   else
      dbms_output.put_line('unable to open cursor');
   end if; 

   close bowl_avg;

end;
/
```

There are a number of contradictions in there.

- In 1 and 2 you're opening a cursor and then checking if there is an open cursor. A error will be raised if the cursor didn't open so you can ignore this step.
- In 5 and 6 you exit if you can't fetch a new record then check if you have a record. This is a contradiction so stage 6 will [(almost)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11273185/can-notfound-return-null-after-a-fetch) always evaluate to true.
- in 7 and 8 you loop, exiting when you don't have a record. As you've just checked (twice) that you do in fact have a record you'll never exit this loop.

If you insist on doing this with cursors then you can remove most of your code and it should work fine:

```
declare

   cursor bowl_avg is
   select sid, matches, bowling_avg, wickets
     from bowling_stats;

   nsid bowling_stats.sid%type;
   nmatches bowling_stats.matches%type;
   nbowling_avg bowling_stats.bowling_avg%type;
   nwickets bowling_stats.wickets%type;

begin

   -- 1. Open Cursor
   open bowl_avg;
   -- 2. Loop
   loop
      -- 3. Get record
      fetch bowl_avg into nsid, nmatches, nbowling_avg, nwickets;
      -- 4. Exit loop if there is no record.
      exit when bowl_avg%notfound;
      -- 5. Perform UPDATE statement.
      update bowling_stats 
         set bowling_avg = nwickets / nmatches 
       where sid = nsid;

   end loop;
   close bowl_avg;

end;
/
```

As always a single UPDATE statement without using loops, cursors or PL/SQL will be significantly more effective.

Comment: Yes ofcourse a single update will suffice, but I've to do this as a project work, & its mandatory to use cursors.

I tried running the optimized code,however there's still an infinite loop. I suspect I'm missing out something very important here. Any guesses ??
Also, I really appreciate your help.I knew my code wasnt that clean, but thanks to you,I know that it was much worse than what I thought...

Comment: I doubt you're getting an infinite loop @Sumedh. As your cursor is selecting every row in the table this may take some time, especially if you don't have an index on `sid`.

Comment: Here it is [working in a SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/f1d7ef/2) @Sumedh.

Comment: Ok, now its working fine....dont know what happened back then.
Thanks for all this help !!